# Excel Formula to Check for Overlaps in Day and Time

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am building an Excel spreadsheet for weekly class schedules. There are 3 columns where people input a schedule in the following format: "[day] [starttime] [endtime]"

Example:

| no. | day | start time | end time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | MTh | 7:00 AM | 9:00 AM |
| 2 | TF | 7:00 AM | 9:00 AM |
| 3 | M | 8:30 AM | 9:30 AM |

**In this example, what I want is for Excel to highlight rows 1 and 3, because they have a time overlap on Monday**

I'm looking for a formula that I can also put inside conditional formatting.

So far, I am only able to highlight time overlaps but have not considered the day. I used a SUMPRODUCT formula below:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((M15<$N$15:$N$26)*(N15>$M$15:$M$26))>1
```

Where M15 is start time and N15 is the end time. The N column range refers to all the end times and M column range refers to all the start times

As much as possible I'd like to use Excel formulas and avoid any VB scripting. But if it's not possible with only formulas, I'm open to suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just add the condition of the **day** column to the formula you provided.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((C2<$D$2:$D$4)*(D2>=$C$2:$C$4)*(B2=$B$2:$B$4))>1
```

[image]

---

---

Update：

Please try the following formulas:

```
SUMPRODUCT((D2>=$C$2:$C$6)*(B2=$B$2:$B$6)*ISNUMBER(FIND("M",$B$2:$B$6))*(COUNT(FIND("M",$B$2:$B$6))>1))>0
SUMPRODUCT((D2>=$C$2:$C$6)*(B2=$B$2:$B$6)*ISNUMBER(FIND("T",$B$2:$B$6))*(COUNT(FIND("T",$B$2:$B$6))>1))>0
SUMPRODUCT((D2>=$C$2:$C$6)*(B2=$B$2:$B$6)*ISNUMBER(FIND("W",$B$2:$B$6))*(COUNT(FIND("W",$B$2:$B$6))>1))>0
SUMPRODUCT((D2>=$C$2:$C$6)*(B2=$B$2:$B$6)*ISNUMBER(FIND("H",$B$2:$B$6))*(COUNT(FIND("H",$B$2:$B$6))>1))>0
SUMPRODUCT((D2>=$C$2:$C$6)*(B2=$B$2:$B$6)*ISNUMBER(FIND("F",$B$2:$B$6))*(COUNT(FIND("F",$B$2:$B$6))>1))>0
SUMPRODUCT((D2>=$C$2:$C$6)*(B2=$B$2:$B$6)*ISNUMBER(FIND("S",$B$2:$B$6))*(COUNT(FIND("S",$B$2:$B$6))>1))>0
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Viki Ji, this works for schedules with one day only. However, it does not work with the example I listed above. The Row 1 schedule is every Monday and Thursday (MTh), then Row 3 is every Monday only. These two rows should be highlighted because they have conflicting time schedules on Monday.

Comment: Hi @Cappujeano, I would be happy to help you, but as you said, the day column may contain two abbreviations for the date.
I wanted to use the FIND function to find cells with the letter M, but the abbreviation for Thursday is Th, which would destroy the search results for Tuesday abbreviated as T. You may need the help from VBA.

Comment: Hi @Viki-Ji, I made a helper column that converts the original days to single characters. The Thursday will be converted from "Th" to just "H", to make all the days single character: "M, T, W, H, F, S". Class days is from Monday to Saturday, no Sunday.

Comment: Hi @Cappujeano, I have updated my answer, please check if it helps.

Comment: You could use `SUBSTITUTE($B$2:$B$6,"Th","H")` to get rid of the Tuesday/Thursday-problem.